EnsureStableOrdering = false is not stopping default sorting in navigation entities on ASP.NET Core OData
Even after setting EnsureStableOrdering = falsein the ODataQuerySettings ODataQueryOptions is still applying default sorting in the collection of navigation entities when expand is specified in the user query, but EnsureStableOrdering = false is working as excepted on primary entity. Also if PageSize is removed from the ODataQuerySettings, sorting is not happening.
public class CustomEnableQuery : EnableQueryAttribute   
{
    private static int _pageSize;

    static CustomEnableQuery()
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                  .Build();
    
        _pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(configuration["pagesize"]);
    }

    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, 
          ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        var result = queryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings { PageSize = _pageSize, EnsureStableOrdering = false, IgnoredQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.Skip });
             
        return result;
    }   
}

What is the correct solution for problem and how to stop default sorting on navigation entities?

Hi Nivash, please check this sample code and tell us if it works for you, thanks

Hi Jason Pan, thanks for the effort. Given sample code is not working as excepted and
if (queryOptions.SelectExpand != null && queryOptions.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause != null)
{
var expandClause = queryOptions.SelectExpand.SelectExpandClause;
foreach (var expandItem in expandClause.SelectedItems.OfType())
{
var navigationProperty = expandItem.NavigationProperty;
}
}
expandItem doest inclue NavigationProperty in it. Also I didn't get how its sorting the order of navigations items into exceoted order.

Hi Nivash, could you create a minimal sample project which can reproduce the issue for us ? Then we can investigate the issue and fix it as soon as possible, thanks for understanding.
